# consider a base 16 adder how to modify the adder so that it can perform a base 8 addition

Tags: boolean-algebra

Consider a base $16$ adder. How can I modify the adder so that it can perform a base $8$ addition?

I expect this question will appear in my exam tomorrow; if anyone can give me a hint or a solution, I'd be grateful. I've tried searching the net and my textbook to get some insight, but nothing is clicking.

Comment: What operations are you allowed to do?

Comment: I just need explanation

Comment: Um, remove one of the bits?

Comment: Is it a mathematics exam? If you are trying to design an adder circuit that outputs carry flags, overflow flags etc., then math.stackexchange is probably not your best first point of call. If you just need the base 8 result, discard the most significant bit.

Comment: @RobArthan How does removing MSB help. If possible give an example